# SQL Server Performance and Query Execution

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Few day before it was hard time..,

I have developed an Application for Online Admission process for College students and was quite successful.

Let me come to the problem i faced,

1. 2 tables were involved in the problem : **Student_AdmissionDetails** ( contains almost 30-35 fields and most of them were having datatype of nvarchar(70)) and the other one was **StudentCategory**
2. After few day from when admission process started, The Student_AdmissionDetails was having about 3,00,000 of records and the StudentCategory was having 4 records
3. I have developed a dashboard where I was suppose to show No of Students applied in each category. and to achieve this I had following Query.

   `Select count(*)`
   `from Student_AdmissionDetails`
   `inner join StudentCategory`
   `on Student_AdmissionDetails.Id=StudentCategory.Id`
   `where CategoryTypeName=@ParameterValue`

The above query gets fired on single page 3 times. and There were 250-300 users who were accessing the same page simultaneously.Along with that on admission form there were 1300-2000 students were filling form at the same time.

The problem that i get was when i ran above query in the sql server it gets fired 1 out of 5 time. **It throws error that An deadlock has occurred while accessing object from memory**(forgive me for not remembering the exact error).

what i'm looking for from the following post is :

- This time i was bit lucky that i haven't made someone unhappy from my coding but Can anyone let me know what can be done to overcome such scenario. What can be best way to handle large DBs
- I tried to figure it out with SQL profiler but since there were 5 more application were running similar kind of mine i was not able to find out howmany users were trying to access the same resource.

I guess following points will be helpful for answering my question.

- The application server and DB server different
- DB server was running on Windows XP(I guess!) and it was having RAM of 128 GBs
- When i executed query from the SQL Server it was taking average of 12-15 second to execute the query.

apologize for writing this big long but i really need help to learn this :)

Comment: If you need this `COUNT` very frequently you might consider using an indexed view which has `COUNT_BIG ... GROUP BY CategoryTypeName` to precalculate the counts. You also are best off [posting the deadlock graph](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10644/deadlock-error-isnt-returning-the-deadlock-sql/10646#10646) and `CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved including indexes.

Comment: Yes..I'm not part of that SQL administration team but they asked me to solve the problem and I was not able to do it..but yes thanks for the reply. I checked the link you posted it only gives deadlock graph..but how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your `SELECT` statement adding `WITH (NOLOCK)`. This will make your results less precise but it seemed that it's enough for your dashboard.

Also it's better to use something like integer `CategoryTypeId` than `CategoryTypeName` in `WHERE` clause.